# add a # between every character except for spaces

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner and can't find anything anywhere else. I'm coding in C# Windows Form. 
Here is what I've got so far:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = "The earth is flat or something";
        string hashtag = "#";            
        stringOutput.Text = input.Replace(" ", "?");           
    }
```

expected output:
    "T#h#e?e#a#r#t#h?i#s?F#l#a#t#"

Comment: add to your question example of input and expected output

Comment: I think I got it: return "T#h#e?e#a#r#t#h?i#s?F#l#a#t#"

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the string and create a new one.

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in input)
{
    result.Append(c);
    if (c != ' ') {
         result.Remove(result.Length - 2, 1);
         result.Append('#');
    }
}

string resultAsString = result.ToString();
```

Or use a regular expression.

Comment: @SnæbjörnJack I edited the answer, it uses `StringBuilder` now. This is the better approach, since `string` is immutable and thus performing such operations inefficent. btw. please mark answer as accepted. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with a simple loop or an `Aggregate` linq query method.

With `foreach` loop:

```
string toBeReplaced = "The earth is flat or something";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var c in toBeReplaced)
{
    if (c != ' ')
    {
        sb.Append(c).Append('#');
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append('?');
    }
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

With `Aggregate` linq extension method:

```
string toBeReplaced = "The earth is flat or something";
string result = toBeReplaced.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => c != ' ' ? sb.Append(c).Append('#') : sb.Append('?')).ToString();
```